# Is it possible to iterate a map, ordered by value?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I've read that it's not possible to change the ordering of a map once created, however I'm wondering if it's possible to iterate through that value in order.

For example:

if I had a `map<int, string> m` where I have the values

```
m[1] = "Matt"
m[2] = "Car"
m[3] = "Arnold"
m[4] = "Bat"
```

rather than changing the ordering in the actual collection is it possible to simply iterate and print out the elements in alphabetical order so `Arnold, Bat, Car, Matt` is outputted?

Comment: Not directly, you need another container filled with map::mapped_type, sort it and display the result (a std::multiset could do that)

Comment: If boost is an option, try bimap: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `std::map` sorts its elements according to their keys, either with the key's `operator <` or a custom comparator. It can't, however, sort itself according to the values.

You may be interested in `std::set<std::string>`, where the keys *are* the values (but you lose "direct" indexing), or a simple `std::vector<std::string>` which you can `std::sort`.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to copy the values out of the `map` into a different structure (for instance a `vector`) and sort them there.

The `map` stores the values in order based on the key and cannot lookup based on value order.

You could create a class that tracks the order of both the orders if you wanted.